# SQL Select Data From Dual in nth row

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I was wondering if we can do a select from dual and place our results at any of the result row? My desired result will be:

```
 CID        EXT
------    ------
ALL       ALL
--        --
DATAA     DATAA
DATAB     DATAB
DATAC     DATAC
```

I was doing

```
SELECT 'ALL' AS "CID"
   , 'ALL' AS "EXT"
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN AS "CID"
      ,  COLUMN AS "EXT"
   FROM TABLEA
)
```

but my results were

```
CID        EXT
------    ------
--        --
ALL       ALL
DATAA     DATAA
DATAB     DATAB
DATAC     DATAC
```

Comment: do you want to show line under "ALL" value? try use two union.

Comment: Adding 2 unions will display the 2nd result I've listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I found out the answer. If I used Jeffrey's answer, I will get

```
ERROR: ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression
```

So, I just changed to

```
SELECT 'ALL' AS "CID" , 'ALL' AS "EXT" FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT * FROM
( 
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN AS "CID",  COLUMN AS "EXT"
 FROM TABLEA ORDER BY "CID", "EXT"
)
```

Then my results work.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly easy to put one arbitrary value at the top of the list.

```
select 'ALL', 1
from dual
union
select your_column_name, 2
from tablea
order by 2, 1
```

Basically, you're supplying a sort order on the fly.

If you want to include the "--", which seems a little odd to me, use a third select and another union.

```
select 'All', 1
from dual
union
select '--', 2
from dual
union
select your_column_name, 3
from tablea
order by 2, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'ALL' AS "CID"
   , 'ALL' AS "EXT"
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN AS "CID"
      ,  COLUMN AS "EXT"
   FROM TABLEA
)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN "CID" = 'ALL' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
        ,"CID"
        ,"EXT";
```

Comment: Hi, yes the result should return two columns, but because two columns have the same results, thus I eliminate one... I'll edit it.